# How to put variable into my query? (Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Need to add user Id for my user, that will be my collection items count + 1.
For example, if I have 100 users, userID of next user will be 101.

```
User.count().exec(function (e, count) {
     console.log(count); // Count = 15, correct.
     newUser.userId = count + 1; // Ain't working...
});
```

So how to add "count" variable to my query?
Or is it more advanced way, to get auto increment (primary key) in mongoose?

Comment: why do you need the id to auto increment? what is your purpose for that? Do you want unique id for all the users, or is there some other motive

Comment: @Ravi Shankar to give every user unique ID and make a link like user/1 ... user/1242. You think it's a bad idea, to add unique ID in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct that there is a different way to get the "primary key" of a document. Use `objName._id` (in your case, `newUser._id`) to access a unique value generated for your document at object creation.

Note that MongoDB is not a relational DB so it's not a primary key and it'll be a string of garbage. If you actually do need an auto incrementing `_id`, you can do that too using the process documented [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) Basically, make a counter with `db.counters.insert`, then create your own function that uses `findAndModify` to get the sequence number you put in `db.counters` and then increment it. Finally, you can insert your document into `User` (or something similar) by setting `_id` to the result of calling that function during the call to insert.